# Конвертер кода с C++ на Python

Tags: python, c++

Есть ли какие-то варианты конвертера с плюсов на питон - может быть программы или что-то еще.
Единственное, что нашел - [Андрей Коп Конвертер](https://github.com/andreikop/cpp2python) (поставил, но по факту так и не смог разобраться, как это работает)

Comment: Вряд ли это имеет смысл, уровень языков и парадигмы программирования на них существенно отличаются. К тому же, из питона ведь можно вызывать откомпилированные С/C++ функции.

Comment: Зачем вам это нужно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое простое решение выглядит так.

- Откомпилируйте ваш C++ код.
- Допустим, исполняемый файл называется file.exe, лежит в каталоге c:\dir1, и ему нужно передать аргумент arg1
- Тогда в python достаточно написать:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['C:\\dir1\\file.exe' ,'arg1'])
```